# What's up with Chris Rock's hands?

Tags: chris-rock

Pardon this screenshot, I literally took a pic of my TV while playing [*CB4* (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106500/).

[image]

Now, I realize he's wearing a ring that spans his entire left hand in this pic, but if you ever see his comedy shows or movies you'll notice that his fingers almost look like they're stuck together.  There's no mention of any deformity on his Wiki page, does anyone know why his hands appear to be deformed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a person who happens to be an actor but is not about anything that has to do with their performance or film history and is, off topic.

Comment: I figured since there was a Kevin Spacey question about his mole, this was fair game.

Answer (score 3):

The ring is pushing the fingers together, and he tends to keep his fingers close anyway. He does not have any deformity of his hands, as seen in countless films, tv episodes, and real life appearances (personally seen him).

[image]
 [src](http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.96815.1313902655!/img/httpImage/gal-toronto-chris-rock-jpg.jpg)

[image] [src](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/huff-wires/20080614/bonnaroo-chris-rock/images/9328a1cd-52a4-4517-82dd-ac0f18309db7.jpg)

Many people think the same thing, but only because Chris always has his hands closed and cup. If anything, that may be, as a skinny man with long fingers, a tendon issue, where slightly tight or short tendons make bent fingers more comfortable. No different than some people who stand with their feet straight out instead of slightly out, bent knees, hand on hips, sitting with you hands palm up, etc.